# How can I repair a repository broken by hg unshelve?

Tags: mercurial, unshelve

I used `hg shelve` in a repository, where I had some unfinished changes because I needed to switch to a different head and perform unrelated changes.

Once my work on the other head was committed, I switched back to the head on which I had originally used `hg shelve` and ran a `hg unshelve` command. This was the result:

```
$ hg unshelve
unshelving change 'default'
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 4 changes to 4 files (+1 heads)
abort: uncommitted changes
$ hg diff
warning: ignoring unknown working parent 893e15ecb5b4!
$
```

I did run `hg head` before and after the `unshelve` command and saw identical outputs. The commit `893e15ecb5b4` never existed, I have no clue where Mercurial got it from.

In case it is of any relevance, I am running Mercurial version 2.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I get my repository back in a working state, and how can I get my shelved changes back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following steps solved the problems for me:

1. Use `hg debugsetparents` to replace the corrupted parent revision number `893e15ecb5b4` with the correct one I had updated to before using `unshelve`
2. Because the above had left me in a state where Mercurial had forgotten all local changes, I had to use `hg manifest | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 touch` to get it to notice any local changes again.
3. The shelved changes could be recovered using `patch -p1 < .hg/shelved/default.patch`, which in my case did exactly what `hg unshelve` should have done for me in the first place.

Comment: `hg debugrebuildstate` is probably what you need instead of #2.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Because it is simpler than what I did? Or because there would be additional information which could be out of sync? If it's the later, then what information would be out of sync?

Comment: It forces Mercurial to rebuild its internal state, so I imagine it is more accurate.  I got the tip from http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2010-04-23-debug-command-tricks/